# Force/simulate change event for <select> on up/down keys

Tags: jquery, select, onchange

## What I have:

I have a  box that toggles the display of various divs depending on the selection.

## What I need:

I need the change event to additionally occur when options are visually changed using up/down arrow keys.

Note: I still additionally need the  box to behave as normal i.e. by mouse clicking.

## My problem:

As most of you already know, the change event is not triggered when options are visually changed using up/down arrow keys.

## My code:

http://jsfiddle.net/GK49r/

**HTML:**

```
<select id="somemenu">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="Trigger">Trigger</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>    
<div id="togglethis">Toggle this.</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#togglethis{display:none;}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#somemenu").change(function() {   
if (this.value == 'Trigger') {
        $('#togglethis').slideDown('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
    } else {
        $('#togglethis').hide();
    }
});
});
```

Note: For some reason, the problem **doesn't** occur on JSFIDDLE i.e. up/down keys trigger change event.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Vtn5Y/   you want something like this?

Comment: issues like this are why there are numerous plugins to replace `select` and other form controls

Comment: Did you mean doesn't occur? Because I tested your code, and I felt it behaved as I would expect it to. If you drop down the options list and use the cursor keys to move the highlight up and down, the change event won't be triggered because the selection isn't final until you hit Enter to make the currently highlighted option the selected option. If you want to "preview" the effect of the selection, maybe you can hook into the keyup/keydown or keypress events of the select and in it check if the key was Up/Down Arrow key and then use that to perform your UI updates.

Comment: @IanO.S. - Sorry, I didn't explicitly explain that I still need the standard mouse-click selection for my select box. I'll edit my question. That's a great solution however to what I originally incorrectly explained.

Comment: @UmarFarooqKhawaja - Correct. That should read "doesn't". Question edited.

Comment: @UmarFarooqKhawaja: Thanks. I used the keyup and keydown events. I basically copied and pasted my .change function and replaced .change with .keyup and repeated this process for .keydown. The toggling now occurs on when up/down keys are used to select an option. It might be best to post your response as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as answer:

I tested your code, and I felt it behaved as I would expect it to. If you drop down the options list and use the cursor keys to move the highlight up and down, the change event won't be triggered because the selection isn't final until you hit Enter to make the currently highlighted option the selected option.

If you want to "preview" the effect of the selection, maybe you can hook into the keyup/keydown or keypress events of the select and in it check if the key was Up/Down Arrow key and then use that to perform your UI updates.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready( function () {

    var index = 0,
        length = $( '#somemenu option' ).length;

    $( '#somemenu' ).on({
        change: function () {    
            if ( this.value === 'Trigger' ) {
                $( '#togglethis').slideDown( 'slow', function() {
                    // Animation complete.
                });
            } else {
                $( '#togglethis' ).hide();
            }
        },
        keydown: function ( event ) {

            if ( event.which === 38 ) {
                index--;
                if ( index < 0 ) {
                    index = length - 1;
                }
            } else if ( event.which === 40 ) { 
                index++;
                if ( index >= length ) {
                    index = 0;
                }
            }

            // Now index refers to the current index of the option element.
            // You can now run your required animation
            // Eg: animate( index );
        }
    }); 
});
```

What you could do is listen to the keydown event on `'#somemenu'` and based off the `event.which` ( 38 for up and 40 for down ), run your events that way

Comment: Thanks for this but where would I incorporate the figures "38" and "40"? I've looked up event.which (http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) but it's not obvious to me.

Comment: I've gotten the events to trigger using .keyup/keydown in addition to .change.